# The name of the last part of link

Tags: url

If there is a link: https://www.example.com/?Test=Im+A+Test&Data=2+Plus+2

what is the last part called "?Test=" and "?Test="

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax

Comment: `"?Test=" and "?Test="` Looks like the same text to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything after the `?` but before the (optional `#`) is known, collectively, as the "query string".

Within that there are individual names and values of the query parameters in the format `name=value`

You can find more out about URLs in many places online including [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax)